# What is the difference between generic node and object node

Tags: java, oop, generics, linked-list

Here is my linkedList class's inner Node class.

```
    private class Node{
    private Node next;
    private T value;

    public Node (T value,Node next){
      this.next=next;
      this.value=value;
    }
}
```

İf i change it like this.

```
    private class Node<T>{
    private Node <T> next;
    private T value;

    public Node (T value,Node<T> next){
      this.next=next;
      this.value=value;
    }
}
```

What happens and which one should i use? I think Node always an object so we don't have to use it with generic data types.Any point that i missed ?

Comment: Yes, `Node` would typically actually use something besides `Object`, so the generic version is more type safe.

Comment: So, can we say if the type is an our object that we create, it doesn't have to be generic ?

Comment: in your first `Node` class, where are you deriving `T` from ? it is compiler error if you don't define `T` somewhere..

Comment: As i say at the starting of my question, it is just a part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I understand is that your code looks something like this

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
    .
    .
    .

    public class Node{
        .
        .
        .
        }
    }
```

Then you should go for

```
private class Node{
    private Node next;
    private T value;

    public Node (T value,Node next){
        this.next=next;
        this.value=value;
    }
}
```

and not for the other. The reason being that when you use the above version, `T` in both classes refers to the type argument provided at object definition, i.e

`LinkedList<String> list; // here String is the type argument for both LinkedList and Node`

and you could simply create Node objects by

`Node someNode=...`

Hence at compile time, the compiler will ensure that only String values are stored in `Node.value` which is what you want.

If you instead go for the other method i.e `Node<T>` then whenever you create objects of type `Node`,  you will again have to type it by coding

`Node<T> someNode = new .. // notice the additional type arguments`

This would clutter your code and beat the primary aim of generics.